# QGIS Compiling 3.6.0 Troubleshooting about PyQt5, SIP, Qscintilla on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: qgis-3, ubuntu, qt, pyqt5, sip

I work on UBUNTU 18.04 LTS/bionic, I am trying to compile QGIS 3.6.0, for an upgrade from QGIS 3.2. 0. I am facing the same trouble as several people the release  compatibility between SIP and PyQT5 an more maybe.

For QGIS 3.2.0 compilation I worked with SIP 4.19.7 and PyQt5 5.11.3, I succeed the compilation.

For QGIS 3.6.0 I try PyQt5 5.12 and SIP 5.19.15 (GPL release). 
I download source tarball from RIVERBANK repository.
I compile each of them, PyQt5 5.12 and SIP 5.19.15,  with configure.py and PyThon 3.6.7. Everything seems OK installation are done. I remove any garbage (I think) about other SIP installation. I installed also QSCIintilla, release 2.11.1. The Qt release is 5.9.5

When, for QGIS 3.6.0,  I prepare the Makefile with  CMake, I have the following messages :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mbariou/WKSCOMPILE/QGIS/QGIS-final-3_6_0/cmake/FindPyQt5.py", line 34, in <module>
    import PyQt5.pyqtconfig
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.pyqtconfig'
```

In fact I have not a such module but I have:

```
/usr/local/py356/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyqtconfig/config.py
```

More, also this error message from CMake :

```
Found SIP version: 4.19.15
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mbariou/WKSCOMPILE/QGIS/QGIS-final-3_6_0/cmake/FindQsci.py", line 45, in <module>
from PyQt5.Qsci import QSCINTILLA_VERSION_STR
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v12.0 to v12.5 but the PyQt5.QtCore module requires API v12.6 

Qsci sip file not found - disabling bindings for derived classes
```

I met the same difficulty when I compiled QGIS 3.2.0 the conflict was the same with other release, bit I succeeded in a random way it seems, in fact I downgrade to the Ubuntu 18.04/bionic distribution about PyQt5 and SIP.

But the following message is recurrent :

```
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v12.0 to v12.5 but the PyQt5.QtCore module requires API v12.6
```

Can somebody deciphers this conflict and what are the release rules to respect between :

- PyQt5,
- sip,
- Qt,
- QGIS ?

Answer (score 1):

**Success it Works**

Finally I find a way to start correctly QGIS 3.6.1, with console Python. But I must say I don't decipher correctly the release relationship between SIP, PyQt5, Qt, and QGIS. My conclusion is sip 4.19.7 works for me.

**How I proceed ?**

1. First I remove any package (through apt-get (Unbuntu) or pip3 (Python) linked to sip, pyqt5, qscintilla
2. second with apt I have done the following install from the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

   sudo apt install sip-dev python3-sip  pyqt5-dev pyqt5.qsci-dev python-sip-dev python3-sip pyqt5-dev-tools python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia python3-pyqt5.qtopengl python3-pyqt5.qtquick python3-pyqt5.qtsql python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit python3-sip python3-sip-dev libqscintilla2-qt5-dev  libqgis-customwidgets libqgis-gui3.4.5 libqscintilla2-qt5-13 openscad  python-pyqt5.qsci python-qgis python-qgis-common python3-pyqt5.qsci

An then, I prepared the Makefile with CMake for QGIS 3.6.1, it was correct
I runned the compile followed by install it succeeded !

On command line : > sip -V => 4.19.7

And  when I run the following python script :

```
import sys
from sip import SIP_VERSION_STR
import sip
import qgis
print("SIP version:", SIP_VERSION_STR)
```

The result was :

SIP version: 4.19.13
PyQt version: 5.10.1
QScintilla version: 2.10.2

**Two** different numbers release for **sip** curious ?

When I start QGIS 3.6.1 , **it failed** about Python console and extension loading => I have the following messages "I translate from french language" : can'load extension 'geomovetools' call error to classFactory() ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name

After some turn around on stackexchange I found the suggestion that I will  have to recompile sip 4.19.7 from code source => https://github.com/eduardosm/sip-4.19.7

With the following configuration command :

```
python3 configure.py --sip-module PyQt5.sip --no-tools
```

And **make** and **sudo make install** for this sip built

I did that as indicated!

Now Everything is OK ! and **QGIS 3.6.1 starts perfectly on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**

Now On my side I have :

> sip -V => 4.19.7 (from /usr/bin/sip)

And  when I run the following script :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR
from PyQt5.Qt import PYQT_VERSION_STR
from sip import SIP_VERSION_STR
import sip
import qgis
from PyQt5.Qsci import QSCINTILLA_VERSION_STR
print(sip.__file__)
print("Qt version:", QT_VERSION_STR)
print("SIP version:", SIP_VERSION_STR)
print("PyQt version:", PYQT_VERSION_STR)
print("QScintilla version:", QSCINTILLA_VERSION_STR)
```

The result is :

```
usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sip.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
Qt version: 5.9.5
SIP version: 4.19.7
PyQt version: 5.10.1
QScintilla version: 2.10.2
```

I hope this can help others, for me it was like an escape from a jail where I was trapped for one month. Enjoy!